# Woocommerce Ajax Filters with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have structure like this

**Brand**

1. Google
2. Apple
3. Microsoft

**Material**

1. Wood
2. Metal
3. Plastik

Basically Brand & Material - are Woocomerce attributes and the rest are variables.

I'm working on ajax filters right now and I need url to look like this

http://example.com/shop?filter_brand=122,123&filter_material=134,45.

Here is, what I have so far this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/v8mgy4bd/141/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dd" data-termik="men">
    <li>
        <label for="">Men</label>
        <input class="ajax-checkbox" data-term="men" data-id="31" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="">Boys</label>
        <input class="ajax-checkbox" data-term="men" data-id="54" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="">Robots</label>
        <input class="ajax-checkbox" data-term="men" data-id="76" type="checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul class="dd" data-termik="women">
    <li>
        <label for="">Women</label>
        <input class="ajax-checkbox" data-term="women" data-id="12" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="">Girls</label>
        <input class="ajax-checkbox" data-term="women" data-id="38" type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="">Barbies</label>
        <input class="ajax-checkbox" data-term="women" data-id="19" type="checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('change', '.ajax-checkbox', function(e) {

    var str = $(".ajax-checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        var term = $(this).data('term');

        var term_ids = [];
        $('.ajax-checkbox:checked').each(function(index, value) {
            var term_id = $(this).data('id');
            term_ids.push(term_id);
        });
        term_ids_unique = $.unique(term_ids);

        return term + '=' + term_ids_unique;

    }).get();

    var uniqueArray = str.filter(function(elem, pos) {
        return str.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    });


    // FINAL URL
    var final_url = uniqueArray;
    console.log(final_url);

});
```

but it doesn't work correct.

Comment: Please tell us precisely what isn't working correctly

Comment: If you click on checkboxes and check console, you will notice, that data is wrong. I wish to have url like this `?filters_brand=21,34&filters_color=33,45. ` Right now I have `?filters_brand=21,34,33,45&filters_color=21,34,33,45 `

Comment: removed meaningless bolding

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this working. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mstrdh/p999v3dy/)

**JS**

```
$(document).on('change', '.ajax-checkbox', function(e) {
    var final_url = '', uniqueArray, selected = {};
  $('.ajax-checkbox:checked').each(function(index,value) {
    var data = $(this).data();
    if (typeof selected[data.term] === "undefined") {
      selected[data.term] = [];
    }
    selected[data['term']].push(data.id);
  });
    for (prop in selected) {
    if (final_url) {
      final_url += '&';
    }
    final_url += prop + '=';
    final_url += selected[prop].join(',');
  }

  console.log(final_url);

});
```